# How to compute a combined likelihood involving multiple datasets?

Tags: time-series, bayesian, maximum-likelihood, markov-chain-montecarlo, likelihood

I have a parametric model that generates $N$ time series, and my goal is to try to find a model where the $N$ predicted time series match $N$ observed time series relatively well. My physics-based model has some free parameters, so I want to use MCMC to explore parameter space. Doing this requires computing a likelihood. This would be straightforward in the simpler case of having just 1 time series to worry about:

$\mathcal{L}\sim\exp(-\chi^2/2)$)

where $\chi^2=\sum_i\frac{(y_{i,pred}-y_{i,obs})^2}{\sigma_i^2}$

just represents how well a single given predicted time series matches the observed time series.

But how would I generalize this to my case where I have $N$ predicted and observed time series, and I want to compute some kind of overall combined likelihood? Making the assumption that the individual time series are all independent of each other, can I just compute the individual likelihood for each time series and then multiply all of them together: $\mathcal{L}_1\times\mathcal{L}_2\times\ldots\times\mathcal{L}_N$?

Comment: Yes: if the time series are independent, then the joint likelihood is the product of the individual likelihoods.

Comment: @RobinRyder awesome, thank you! I'm guessing things would get a lot messier and harder if the time series were not independent. What could possibly go wrong in my MCMC parameter estimation if I assumed independence despite there being some underlying correlation that I didn't test/account for? And how would things change from computing the joint likelihood simply as the product of the individual likelihoods?

Comment: If you treat the series as independent when they are not, all sorts of things can go wrong. At the very least, the pseudo-likelihood will probably be too peaked; it can also change the position of the mode(s), the number of modes, etc.
If the series are not independent, you need to model the dependence, i.e. the structure of the correlation. For instance, you might want to look into hierarchical models.

Comment: This paper might be helpful: http://file.scirp.org/Html/7-1240445_54078.htm Otherwise, let me know